# Ubuntu 15.10 keeps randomly crashing to login

Tags: google-chrome, 15.10

I am randomly getting logged out on Ubuntu-Gnome 15.10, while in the middle of some work. It takes me back to login screen. It mostly happens when I am using Chrome browser, but I am not sure on whether there is any causality there.
This is on a System 76 64-bit laptop.

i'm not sure what diagnostics i can use to troubleshoot the cause, if anyone can assist I would appreciate it!

Update:
I am able to consistently reproduce the crash!
after crashing, i logged back in, opened LibreOffice Writer, had to do a file recovery, i had 2 documents to recover, it recovered them, then i click on the LibreOffice icon to switch to the other document, and it instantly crashes to login screen.
has anyone seen this or similar behavior?
how would i troubleshoot this?

Comment: Yes, I have similar behaviour and it's starting to get really annoying. I'm on a Lenovo X230T under Ubuntu 15.10 and it wasn't like this until a month or so ago.

Crashes seems to happen when I'm using LibreOFfice, but not exclusively. I cannot reproduce it reliably. Every time when I log back in I get a crash window, offering to report it (compiz death, or sometimes unity-settings-daemon as well), but it never finishes the process to report it (something else dies??).

Comment: Can you provide some log files? I'm thinking of `dmesg` and the likes.

Comment: Is this related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/1509846 ? I don't understand the fix, anyway.

Comment: I gave up on fixing this and uninstalled LibreOffice and installed OpenOffice, problem solved.